# Footer is floating in middle of page despite CSS

Tags: html, css

I am fairly new to HTMl and CSS. I had my footer stuck to the bottom of the page no problem and then something changed and I cannot figure it out. When I go to a page without a lot of content the footer sits in the middle of the page. On pages with content, it works as it should. I have read countless other posts with the same issue and nothing seems to work. Using "position:fixed" makes the footer stuck to the bottom of the "viewport" not the page itself. Thus when I switch to another page with scrollable content, the footer shows itself behind the page content. I've tried adding "overflow:hidden", "bottom:0;", "left:0" and "right:0" to .main-footer and that doesn't fix it. I don't know what I'm missing. I have already spent a few hours looking up answers and trying to solve this issue.

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    color: #777;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
}

/* Styles for navigation menus */
nav ul {
    margin: 0;
}

nav li{
    display: inline-block;   
}

nav a {
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: .5em;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 350ms;
}
nav a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(215, 200, 200, .3);
    border-radius: 2px;
}

/*Style for MAIN navigation menu*/
.main-nav {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: lighter;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(215, 200, 200, .3);
}

.main-nav li {
    padding: 0 5%;
}

.main-header {
    background-image: url('headerfooterimages/headerpicture.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    
}

/* Style for Page Title/Logo */
.titleLogo {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 4em;
    font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
    color: white;
}

.titleLogo-large {
    font-size: 6em;
}

/*Styles for sections of content on page*/
.content-section {
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 2em;
}

.content-container {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
}

.section-header {
    font-family: Impact;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
}

/*Styling the footer for each page*/
.main-footer {
    background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45);
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 75px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    margin: auto;
}

.footer-text {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: rgba(128, 128, 128);
    display: inline-flex;
}

.footer-text:hover {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    cursor: crosshair;
    color:rgb(188, 188, 188);
}

.main-footer-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.main-footer-container ul {
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: end;
}
/*Styling the social media links in the footer*/
.footer-nav li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    transition: 350ms;
}

.footer-nav img {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

.footer-nav li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(215, 200, 200, .3);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-top: 3px;
}

/*Styling buttons across the whole site*/
.btn {
    background-color: #349aff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 1em;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #2090ff;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: none;
}

/*Styling the cart menu option in the main navigation*/
.cart-container{
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: auto;
}

.cart-icon {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    height: 25px;
}

.cart-text {
    display:inline-block;
    color: white;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

.cart-text:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/*Styling shop items*/
.shop-item {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px;
}

.shop-item-image {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 200px;
}

.shop-item-title {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: #333;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.shop-item-details {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.shop-item-price {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333;
    width: 50%;
}

.shop-item-button {
    display: block;
}

.shop-items {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

/*Styling the image carousel*/
.carousel {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}

.carousel > ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

.carousel-container {
    margin: auto;
    align-items: center;
}

/*Styling the buttons on the carousel*/
.carousel-button {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 .25rem;
    z-index: 2;
    background: none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    border: none;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-120%);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    cursor: pointer;
    

}

.carousel-button:hover, .carousel-button:focus {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.carousel-button:focus {
    outline: 1px solid black;
}

.carousel-button.prev {
    left: 1rem;
}

.carousel-button.next {
    right: 12rem;
}

/*Styling and formatting the next image effect for the image carousel*/
.slide {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    object-fit: fill;
    transition: 400ms opacity ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 200ms;
    
}

.slide > img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70%;
    height: 80%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    object-fit: cover;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.slide[data-active] {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
    transition-delay: 0ms;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "enUS">

    <head>

        <title>Modern Style</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abel&family=Bebas+Neue" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="favicon" href="favicon.ico">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
            <script src="script.js" defer></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <header class="main-header">
                <nav class="nav main-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="store.html">STORE</a></li>
                        <li class="cart-container"><a href="cart.html"><img class="cart-icon" src="headerfooterimages/cart.png" alt="A shopping cart icon">
                            <div class="cart-text">Shopping Cart</div></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

            <h1 class="titleLogo titleLogo-large">Modern Style Website</h1>
        </header>

        <section class="content-section content-container">
            <h2 class="section-header">ABOUT</h2>
            <p>
                This is placeholder text. This is placeholder text. This is placeholder text. This is placeholder text. This is placeholder text. 
                This is placeholder text. This is placeholder text. This is placeholder text. This is placeholder text. This is placeholder text. 
                This is placeholder text. This is placeholder text. This is placeholder text. This is placeholder text. This is placeholder text. 
                This is placeholder text. This is placeholder text. This is placeholder text. This is placeholder text. This is placeholder text. 
                This is placeholder text. This is placeholder text. This is placeholder text. This is placeholder text. This is placeholder text. 
                This is placeholder text. This is placeholder text. This is placeholder text. This is placeholder text. This is placeholder text. 
            </p>
        </section>

    </body>

    <footer class="main-footer">
        <div class="main-footer-container">
            <h2 class="footer-text">Modern Style Website</h2>
            <ul class="nav footer-nav">
                <li><a href="https://www.Facebook.com" target="_blank" alt="Link to Facebookcom"><img src="headerfooterimages/Facebook-Logo.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.Instagram.com" target="_blank" alt="Link to Instagram.com"><img src="headerfooterimages/Instagram-Logo.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.Twitter.com" target="_blank" alt="Link to Twitter.com"><img src="headerfooterimages/Twitter-Logo.png"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>

</html>
```

Comment: sorry if this might seem obvious, but have you tried using `position: absolute` and applying those fixes that you mentioned in your post? Or is there another reason you cannot do that?

Comment: When I put "position: absolute", on the pages with content that requires you to scroll down the page to see the content, the footer is stuck right over the bottom of my first paragraph and other content is pushed below the footer. Whereas with "position: fixed" the content of the page would overlap the footer. With "position: relative", on pages with content that requires you to scroll down to view the content, the footer is pushed below the view of the page only showing the very top of the footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as you have declared the `body` to be `100vh`, you can utilize this empty space with `margin-top: auto`.

On `main-footer`, remove `margin: auto` and replace it with `margin-top: auto`. This way, it will convert the remaining space on the `body` element into a `margin-top`-value for the `main-footer` element.

##### On another note,

make sure to include the `<footer>`-element **BEFORE** your closing `</body>`-tag, the footer is supposed to be inside the `<body>`-element.

Also, in your CSS reset, I would consider adding `margin: 0;` to avoid white bars on your site.

**Codepen** (because the code snippet is so long): https://codepen.io/sigurdmazanti/pen/ZErJzEK

```css
.main-footer {
    background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45);
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 75px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    /*margin: auto;*/
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sigurd! This fixed it instantly. Thank you for the explanation as to HOW it fixes it as well, extremely helpful for a newbie.

Comment: You've really taken your time to help me out today. I didn't even know about making a reset.css and from reading I guess most novices don't, I supposed even more so when "self-taught". I will make sure to add margin to reset.css. I had completely overlooked the footer being outside the body, thank you for pointing that out as well.

Comment: Hey @XanderJuneau - you can do a complete CSS reset, but they can be a bit overkill sometimes - you already have one at line 1-5 where you specify `box-sizing: border box`! The `*` selector targets everything in your HTML, if you didn't know. I just thought `margin: 0;` would fit into that, because there was unknown margin appearing in the codepen :) glad to help!

Comment: Keep in mind this will reset **ALL** `margin` values on your site, unless you specifically declare them!

Answer (score 0):

just use this css code:

i have added multiple values to body and remove margin from footer

```
*, *::before, *::after {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
      color: #777;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      min-height: 100vh;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      align-content: space-between;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: stretch;
    }

    /* Styles for navigation menus */
    nav ul {
      margin: 0;
    }

    nav li{
      display: inline-block;
    }

    nav a {
      display: inline-flex;
      padding: .5em;
      margin-top: 5px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      transition: 350ms;
    }
    nav a:hover {
      background-color: rgba(215, 200, 200, .3);
      border-radius: 2px;
    }

    /*Style for MAIN navigation menu*/
    .main-nav {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 1.1em;
      font-weight: lighter;
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(215, 200, 200, .3);
    }

    .main-nav li {
      padding: 0 5%;
    }

    .main-header {
      background-image: url('headerfooterimages/headerpicture.jpg');
      background-size: cover;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      background-blend-mode: multiply;
      padding-bottom: 25px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;

    }

    /* Style for Page Title/Logo */
    .titleLogo {
      text-align: center;
      margin: auto;
      font-size: 4em;
      font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
      color: white;
    }

    .titleLogo-large {
      font-size: 6em;
    }

    /*Styles for sections of content on page*/
    .content-section {
      margin: 1em;
      padding: 2em;
    }

    .content-container {
      max-width: 900px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 0 1.5em;
    }

    .section-header {
      font-family: Impact;
      font-weight: normal;
      color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
    }

    /*Styling the footer for each page*/
    .main-footer {
      background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45);
      padding: 5px;
      position: relative;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 75px;
      border-top: 1px solid black;
      
    }

    .footer-text {
      font-size: 25px;
      color: rgba(128, 128, 128);
      display: inline-flex;
    }

    .footer-text:hover {
      text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
      cursor: crosshair;
      color:rgb(188, 188, 188);
    }

    .main-footer-container {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .main-footer-container ul {
      flex-grow: 1;
      text-align: end;
    }
    /*Styling the social media links in the footer*/
    .footer-nav li {
      list-style: none;
      display: inline-flex;
      transition: 350ms;
    }

    .footer-nav img {
      border-radius: 5px;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
    }

    .footer-nav li:hover {
      background-color: rgba(215, 200, 200, .3);
      border-radius: 5px;
      padding-left: 3px;
      padding-right: 3px;
      padding-top: 3px;
    }

    /*Styling buttons across the whole site*/
    .btn {
      background-color: #349aff;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 1em;
      color: white;
      padding: 8px 16px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 8px;
      font-weight: bold;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

    .btn:hover {
      background-color: #2090ff;
      cursor: pointer;
      box-shadow: none;
    }

    /*Styling the cart menu option in the main navigation*/
    .cart-container{
      display: inline-flex;
      margin: auto;
    }

    .cart-icon {
      float: left;
      clear: left;
      height: 25px;
    }

    .cart-text {
      display:inline-block;
      color: white;
      padding: 2px;
      margin-top: 1px;
    }

    .cart-text:hover {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }

    /*Styling shop items*/
    .shop-item {
      display: block;
      margin: 50px;
    }

    .shop-item-image {
      display: block;
      margin: 10px;
      height: 200px;
    }

    .shop-item-title {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 1.1em;
      color: #333;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .shop-item-details {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }

    .shop-item-price {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      color: #333;
      width: 50%;
    }

    .shop-item-button {
      display: block;
    }

    .shop-items {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      justify-content: space-around;
    }

    /*Styling the image carousel*/
    .carousel {
      width: 600px;
      height: 400px;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
    }

    .carousel > ul {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      list-style: none;
    }

    .carousel-container {
      margin: auto;
      align-items: center;
    }

    /*Styling the buttons on the carousel*/
    .carousel-button {
      position: absolute;
      padding: 0 .25rem;
      z-index: 2;
      background: none;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
      border: none;
      border-radius: .25rem;
      font-size: 2.5rem;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-120%);
      color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
      cursor: pointer;


    }

    .carousel-button:hover, .carousel-button:focus {
      color: white;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    }

    .carousel-button:focus {
      outline: 1px solid black;
    }

    .carousel-button.prev {
      left: 1rem;
    }

    .carousel-button.next {
      right: 12rem;
    }

    /*Styling and formatting the next image effect for the image carousel*/
    .slide {
      position: absolute;
      inset: 0;
      opacity: 0;
      object-fit: fill;
      transition: 400ms opacity ease-in-out;
      transition-delay: 200ms;

    }

    .slide > img {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 70%;
      height: 80%;
      border-radius: 10px;
      object-fit: cover;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

    .slide[data-active] {
      opacity: 1;
      z-index: 1;
      transition-delay: 0ms;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS. It will also top align your content-section. I fixed horizontal scroll as well. Just make sure to keep your website content inside of body tags. Your footer was outside of the body tag.

```
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    color: #777;
}

body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   min-height: 100vh;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

/* Styles for navigation menus */
nav ul {
    margin: 0;
}

nav li{
    display: inline-block;   
}

nav a {
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: .5em;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 350ms;
}
nav a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(215, 200, 200, .3);
    border-radius: 2px;
}

/*Style for MAIN navigation menu*/
.main-nav {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: lighter;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(215, 200, 200, .3);
}

.main-nav li {
    padding: 0 5%;
}

.main-header {
    background-image: url('headerfooterimages/headerpicture.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    
}

/* Style for Page Title/Logo */
.titleLogo {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 4em;
    font-family: 'Bebas Neue';
    color: white;
}

.titleLogo-large {
    font-size: 6em;
}

/*Styles for sections of content on page*/
.content-section {
    margin: 1em;
    padding: 2em;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    flex-grow: 1;

}

.content-container {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.section-header {
    font-family: Impact;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: rgb(34, 34, 34);
}

/*Styling the footer for each page*/
.main-footer {
    background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45);
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 75px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    margin: auto;

}

.footer-text {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: rgba(128, 128, 128);
    display: inline-flex;
}

.footer-text:hover {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    cursor: crosshair;
    color:rgb(188, 188, 188);
}

.main-footer-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.main-footer-container ul {
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: end;
}
/*Styling the social media links in the footer*/
.footer-nav li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    transition: 350ms;
}

.footer-nav img {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

.footer-nav li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(215, 200, 200, .3);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-top: 3px;
}

/*Styling buttons across the whole site*/
.btn {
    background-color: #349aff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 1em;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #2090ff;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: none;
}

/*Styling the cart menu option in the main navigation*/
.cart-container{
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: auto;
}

.cart-icon {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    height: 25px;
}

.cart-text {
    display:inline-block;
    color: white;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}

.cart-text:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/*Styling shop items*/
.shop-item {
    display: block;
    margin: 50px;
}

.shop-item-image {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 200px;
}

.shop-item-title {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: #333;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.shop-item-details {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.shop-item-price {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333;
    width: 50%;
}

.shop-item-button {
    display: block;
}

.shop-items {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

/*Styling the image carousel*/
.carousel {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}

.carousel > ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

.carousel-container {
    margin: auto;
    align-items: center;
}

/*Styling the buttons on the carousel*/
.carousel-button {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 .25rem;
    z-index: 2;
    background: none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    border: none;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-120%);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    cursor: pointer;
    

}

.carousel-button:hover, .carousel-button:focus {
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.carousel-button:focus {
    outline: 1px solid black;
}

.carousel-button.prev {
    left: 1rem;
}

.carousel-button.next {
    right: 12rem;
}

/*Styling and formatting the next image effect for the image carousel*/
.slide {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    object-fit: fill;
    transition: 400ms opacity ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 200ms;
    
}

.slide > img {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 70%;
    height: 80%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    object-fit: cover;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.slide[data-active] {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
    transition-delay: 0ms;
}
```